# Back and previous button in website

Tags: jquery, jsp

I am beginner for java,  My  project contains two web pages one is login page and other is main page which has three frames with logout button,When i click on log out it will again go to page which ask the user to login . but after sign out when i click previous button available on browser it is going to the main page ,What exactly has to be done to stop accessing the data once after log-out.
Please help me out

Thanks in Avance

Regards,
Akhila

Comment: There are thousands of blog posts, tutorials etc. about this topic. Have you even tried to use Google?

Comment: You send headers that prevent caching.

Comment: You may wanna read about servlet filter. Take a look [here](http://www.journaldev.com/1933/java-servlet-filter-example-tutorial)

Answer (score -1):

You need to apply session management to deal with this issue. When user logs in create a session(on log in page).

```
HttpSession session=new HttpSession();
```

Then on the main page check if a session exists or not.Like this-

```
if(session.isNew())
{
//redirect to login page}
}
else
{
//Rest of your code.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for everyone  who have helped in solving my problem .... :)